# How to capture high-def content from a cable box to a PC?

Tags: video, hdtv, hdvideo, tuner-card

#### Situation

We have about 60 episodes of "The Little Einsteins" saved on our cable DVR, a [Scientific Atlanta Explorer 8300HD](http://www.cisco.com/web/consumer/support/settop_8300hddvr.html). My daughter loves the show and I am terrified that some freak accident will wipe out our hard-earned collection. So I would like to digitize the copies to a PC for backup. It would also be nice to throw them on a video iPod for trips.

#### Desired solution

I would ideally like to be able to encode the videos in 1080i. Obviously best case would be to somehow do a pure digital copy, but I'm resigned to the fact that I will probably have to play the episodes one-by-one and do an analog capture. I'm willing to spend up to a few hundred dollars on a solution.

#### What I've looked at already

- [Newegg >> "Video Cards & Video Devices" >> "Editing & Capture"](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=2010380047%201685342852&bop=And&ActiveSearchResult=True&Order=RATING). All of these devices look to be standard definition only.
- [Newegg >> "Video Cards & Video Devices" >> "Tuner Card"](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=2010380047%201685342847&name=Tuner%20Card&ActiveSearchResult=True). I don't need a TV Tuner, I just want to capture high-def video.
- A device called the [Blackmagic Intensity](http://www.blackmagic-design.com/products/intensity/), reviewed [here](http://worldtv.com/blog/software_tools/hdmi_video_capture_with_intensity.php). I can only find one review, and it appears the device is Mac OSX only.

So, I thought this would be an ideal quesiton to pose to the SuperUser community: **what are some affordable ways to liberate the high-def content from a cable company's DVR?**

Comment: I really really **really** doubt that Litte Einsteins are broadcast  in 1080i. So saving it in that format will only be a waste of space. Cartoons are usually highly compressible and should look fine in lower resolutions.

Comment: We get DisneyHD and regular old Disney. The stuff broadcast on the non-HD Disney channel looks like complete crap. I agree with you, cartoons should not require 1080i, but compared to the compressed garbage being streamed down the non-HD channels, it's a huge difference.

Comment: Interesting. I suppose its true what they say. Once you go HD there is no turning back.

Comment: Note that the Blacmagic card does run on windows. **Intensity features the latest HDMI technology for the highest quality capture and playback on Windows™ or Mac OS X™ computers. **

Comment: I am in the same position - nearing 95% full on the DVR.  Didnt want to create a duplicate question - all I want to do is offload the shows I recorded to a DVD for storage and playback at a later time, pretty much like we used to be able to do with a VCR.  Doesnt have to be HD - just a recorded copy so I can delete everything off the DVR and..... start that process over again I suppose..

Comment: @optimalsolutions: I'm still waiting on any kind of way to do this, as well. Might add a bounty.

Answer (score 1):

[This link](http://www.cisco.com/web/consumer/support/settop_8300hddvr.html#~features) says that you should have an external SATA connection. If you hook up a hdd to that you can copy your data to that for backup (or later connect it to your computer for conversion).

Comment: Unfortunately, my cable box runs "PASSPORT", not "SARA", so the eSATA port is deactivated. http://www.wkblog.com/tivo/2007/09/esata-port-activated-on-more-scientific-atlanta-boxes/

Comment: Often the output formats are encrypted when written to external disks to prevent piracy.  I know people have cracked the encryption on some of the devices though.

Answer (score 0):

If the DVR has component or USB output, there are a number of HDMI converters available:

- [RCA 2 HDMI Converters](http://www.monoprice.com/products/search.asp?spcDB=10114&keyword=hdmi%20analog)

From there, an HDMI 2 DVI adapter is easy to find.

Answer (score 0):

Attach a video capture card to your computer.  [Hauppauge](http://www.hauppauge.com/site/products/prods.html) makes a wide range of products to do this.  You can then connect your DVR to the capture card and record/encode anything on your DVR.

The only drawback is your DVR.  DVRs do not support HDCP out.  This is designed so that pirates cant make high quality copies from digital sources easily.  So the output will be less than 1080p.  Im not sure what the output will be, but it should still be more than acceptable.